# How to fill in all input fields according to a selected object

Tags: typescript, mongodb, angular-cli

So I'm currently building an application for sports events management, using AngularCLI, and MongoDB for my database.
I'm actually working on a page who allows you to create an event (with a name, a location), you have a couple of others things that you can add to your event (import the complete list of athletes taking part in the event for exemple), and the last thing I added is to add age categories to your event.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hU1b.png)

Here you have the web page, as you can see, you can add an age category (AGCode here), a label (name of the event), and the category year limits.
When you click on the button save, the new event that you just have created will be save in a collection in MongoDB, same for your Age category.
You can also see that in the right of the first input field, you have a drop-down menu, which groups together each existing age category, and when you select one of those categories, the field is automatically filled with the value selected in the drop-down menu.

Here is my view :

```
<div class="h2">Age Category</div>
    <div class="level">
      <div *ngFor="let cat of event.ageGroup; index as idCat">
        <div class="button-line">
          <input type="button" value="delete the category" (click)="deleteAgeGroup(idCat)" style="background-color: rgb(125, 8, 8); color: white;">
        </div>
        <div class="field-line">
          <div class="label">AGCode</div>
          <div class="field">
            <input [(ngModel)]="cat.AGCode" class="short-label">
            <select [(ngModel)]="cat.AGCode">
              <option *ngFor="let cats of tabCat">{{cats.AGCode}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-line">
          <div class="label">Label</div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cat.label" class="label">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-line">
          <div class="label">start Year Age</div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="number" min="2000" max="2023" step="1" [(ngModel)]="cat.startYearAge" class="label">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-line">
          <div class="label">end Year Age</div>
          <div class="field">
            <input type="number" min="2000" max="2023" step="1" [(ngModel)]="cat.endYearAge" class="label">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-line" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
        <input type="button" value="Add a age category" (click)="addAgeGroup()" style="background-color: rgb(8, 125, 39); color: white;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-line" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
        <input type="button" value="Save" (click)="save()" style="background-color: rgb(8, 125, 39); color: white;">
    </div>
```

What I want to do is, when you select one the existing age category in the drop-down menu (if you have understood correctly, this represents an object in my AgeGroup collection), the others fields will be automatically filled with the values of my object.
Is there a way to do this?
I thought about an ngIf, or maybe there is a way to link each fields with my first input field (maybe with ngModel??), but help here would be appreciated.